"TypeError: Invalid parameters." when signAndSendTransaction
have been trying to interact with a program through web3.js in the browser. Here's the code for creating the transaction:
const transaction = new solanaWeb3.Transaction();

const instruction = new solanaWeb3.TransactionInstruction({
    keys: [{
            pubkey: stakeAccount, // is PublicKey
            isSigner: false,
            isWritable: true
        },
        {
            pubkey: mintAccount, // is PublicKey
            isSigner: false,
            isWritable: true
        },
        {
            pubkey: rewardMintAccount, // is PublicKey
            isSigner: false,
            isWritable: true
        },
        {
            pubkey: mint, // is PublicKey
            isSigner: false,
            isWritable: true
        },
        {
            pubkey: rewardMint, // is PublicKey
            isSigner: false,
            isWritable: true
        },
        {
            pubkey: userPublicKey, // is PublicKey
            isSigner: true,
            isWritable: true
        },
        {
            pubkey: SYSTEM_PROGRAM_ID, // is PublicKey
            isSigner: false,
            isWritable: false
        },
        {
            pubkey: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, // is PublicKey
            isSigner: false,
            isWritable: false
        },
        {
            pubkey: ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, // is PublicKey
            isSigner: false,
            isWritable: false
        }
    ],
    programId: programId // is PublicKey
});
transaction.add(instruction);

Here's the IDL of the program for reference:
{
  "name": "initializeAccounts",
  "accounts": [
    {
      "name": "stakeAccount",
      "isMut": true,
      "isSigner": false
    },
    {
      "name": "associatedAccount",
      "isMut": true,
      "isSigner": false
    },
    {
      "name": "rewardAssociatedAccount",
      "isMut": true,
      "isSigner": false
    },
    {
      "name": "mint",
      "isMut": true,
      "isSigner": false
    },
    {
      "name": "rewardMint",
      "isMut": true,
      "isSigner": false
    },
    {
      "name": "user",
      "isMut": true,
      "isSigner": true
    },
    {
      "name": "systemProgram",
      "isMut": false,
      "isSigner": false
    },
    {
      "name": "tokenProgram",
      "isMut": false,
      "isSigner": false
    },
    {
      "name": "associatedTokenProgram",
      "isMut": false,
      "isSigner": false
    }
  ],
  "args": []
}

Still when I try to send the transaction like so:
await window.solana.signAndSendTransaction(transaction);

it returns the following error:

VM488:14 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Invalid parameters.
at Object.apply (:14:31)
at HTMLButtonElement. (scripts.js:260:50)

I've looked around for help online, but couldn't find any answers. Would love some assistance on this.
